# cipher suites support for kafka

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, java-security

How do I know which cipher suites are supported for kaka.

I am using kafka `kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1` version and

**Java version**

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

appreciate any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strength of Kafka cryptography depends on your **java cryptography extension (jce)** version. And Kafka can use all algorithms that are supported by jce (that are numerous).

Default java has limited support for cipher algorithms for instance max key length for AES is 128. For using maximum security you can download unlimited jce from [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and update it in your jre libs directory.